# How to use <list> with modelView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to Graph Excel data using ChartJS. 
Visual Studio is saying that `List<Graphs> does not contain a definition for Answers.`

I can't find anything wrong with my code, though. Though, I've only been using VS for the past two days.

Can someone look at my code and maybe find a mistake, or two? Thanks!

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ReinovaGrafieken.Models;


namespace ReinovaGrafieken.Models
{
    public class GraphDataViewModel
    {
        public List<Graphs> GraphData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Graphs Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ReinovaGrafieken.Models;

namespace ReinovaGrafieken.Models
{
    public class Graphs
    {
        public string Names { get; set; }
        public string AnswerHeaders { get; set; }
        public int Answers { get; set; }
        public string Questions { get; set; }
        public string AnteOrPost { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a piece of the code from the View:

```
@model ReinovaGrafieken.Models.GraphDataViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<h2>Dashboard</h2>

<div id="chart_container">
    <canvas id="bar_chart"></canvas>

    <script>
        var answers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.GraphData.Answers));
        var labels = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.GraphData.Names));
```

This is where I got the ideas from, where it does work for that person:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs&t=2787s`

Comment: `GraphData` is `List<Graphs>`. A `List<T>` does not contain a property named `Answers` (it contains properties such as `Count()`). Its the `Graphs` class which contains property `Answer`

Comment: Its not clear what you need for the plugin. Do you want a collection containing all the values of the `Answer` property?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah. I want to create 5 or so lists from an Excel sheet. These lists will have to be useable in the View for ChartJS. (for 50 or so charts)

Comment: Yes but what do you need `repArray` and `ages` to be? For example `Model.GraphData.Select(x => x.Answers)` would give you an array containing each `Answer` value.

Comment: If on the other hand you need access to all values, then its just `Model.GraphData` which would generate `[{Names someValue, AnswerHeaders someValue, .... }, {{Names someValue, AnswerHeaders someValue, .... }, { ... }]`

Comment: Ah, `repArray, ages` are placeholders. I've updated the post.
So I don't need to use my ViewModel class in order to access every list?

Comment: Then its `var answers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.GraphData.Select(x => x.Answers));` albeit, it seems odd that you would want that for a graph -
 which would need at least 2 properties (but if you having to do that, then you view model is wrong in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

`GraphData` is collection of `Graph`. So `Answers` is accessible property on `Graph` and not `GraphData`.

Comment: But then how do I acces every property? ( 'Answers', 'AnswerHeaders', etc))

Comment: what is the purpose of `List<Graph>` not sure if you would like to iterate through collection and access each element `Answers` property : `foreach(var item in @Model.GraphData) { var  answers = item.Answers; /*do what you want to do with 'answers` */ }`

Comment: I got it from a video I added to the post. I just need to access everything as lists. A list for `Names`, `Answers` etc

Answer (score 1):

Like @Stephen Muecke wrote, `List<T>`  does not contain a property named `Answers`.
You could take element, which you need like this:

```
@Model.GraphData.First().Answers
```

(get first element from the list). 
Or you can use `.Foreach()` method